# Insert into sqlite database with variables in C++ (Visual C++ 2010)

Tags: visual-c++, sqlite, insert

I would like to insert data into my sqlite database by using variables instead of doing : "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(NULL,'" + to_string(myVar) + "');".

Is there another way in sqlite3 to insert data into the database ? I saw an exemple in Objective C that uses : sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbName,sqlRequest, -1, &args, NULL);

Is this a good idea to use the equivalent of this function in C++ to be able to insert data from variables ?
I work with Visual C++ 2010.

Thank you

Comment: What database API are you using?

Comment: I use sqlite api version 3 in C++ : http://sqlite.org/c3ref/intro.html http://sqlite.org/download.html

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the SQLite C API directly, you have to use the [sqlite3_prepare_v2](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) and [sqlite3_bind_*](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) functions.